# Angular 8: trying to catch constructor, but not return Value

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to call a constructor from an Angular 8 Service;

I did this CRUD op before, but this time is not working properly, and I can't find why.

I been trying many things at this time I have an headache, and I don't know what to do.

Please I apreciate who helps me to fix this.

#### Constructor Object

```
export class Book {
  constructor(
    _id = "",
    title = "",
    author = "",
    genre = "",
    details: any,
    status: any,
    current: any
  ) {
    this._id = _id;
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.genre = genre;
    this.details = details;
    this.status = status;
    this.current = current;
  }
  _id: string;
  title: string;
  author: string;
  genre: string;
  details: {
    publisher: string;
    year: string;
    isbn: number;
    categories: string;
    language: string;
    pages: number;
  };
  status: {
    loan: boolean;
    sold: boolean;
    lost: boolean;
    donated: boolean;
  };
  current: {
    owner: string;
    location: string;
    edition: string;
  };
```

#### Angular Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Book } from './bookmodel';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class BookserviceService {
  selectedBook: Book;
  Book: Book[];

  readonly URL_API = `http://localhost:9000/`;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

**ERROR LINE***
    this.selectedBook = new Book(); <-- (Expected 7 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554) bookmodel.ts(3, 5): An argument for '_id' was not provided.)

  }
  postBook(book: Book) {
    return this.http.post(this.URL_API, book);
  }
  getBook() {
    return this.http.get(this.URL_API);
  }
  putBook(book: Book) {
    return this.http.put(this.URL_API + `/${book._id}`, book);
  }
  deleteBook(_id: string) {
    return this.http.delete(this.URL_API + `/${_id}`);
  }
  searchBook(queryString: string) {
    const  baseURL = this.URL_API + queryString;
    return this.http.get(baseURL);

  }
}
```

Comment: The answer lies in the error. You are not passing any parameter in your book constructor. Please pass the required parameters. Or make your constructor have parameter optional by having ? after param name like this - details?: any

Comment: thank yo so much, it work...